# SQL Query to show for all the users created YESTERDAY, How many sent invitations?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following query:

```
SELECT floor(datediff(u.created_at, curdate()) / 1) AS days_ago,
       count(DISTINCT u.id) AS "New Users in Cohort", 
       count(DISTINCT i.user_id) AS "Uniq Users who invited Cohort",
count(DISTINCT u.id) / count(DISTINCT i.user_id) AS "% who invite"
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN invitations i
     ON u.id = i.user_id
WHERE u.onboarding_started_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY days_ago;
```

I'm trying to get the query to return the following:

```
+----------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------+
| days_ago | New Users | Unique Users who Invited | % who invite |
+----------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------+
|        1 |        20 |                       10 | 50%          |
+----------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------+
```

New users would be where u.created_at is the day the query is using

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

You have not said enough for me to judge whether `DISTINCT` is needed.

`LEFT` seems unnecessary.

"Yesterday" is `... >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND ... < CURDATE()

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT u.id) AS "New Users in Cohort", 
       count(DISTINCT i.user_id) AS "Uniq Users who invited Cohort",
       count(DISTINCT u.id) / count(DISTINCT i.user_id) AS "% who invite"
FROM users u 
JOIN invitations i
     ON u.id = i.user_id
WHERE u.onboarding_started_at IS NOT NULL
  AND u.created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND u.created_at  < CURDATE()
```

If you wanted the counts for multiple days, then I would use `DATE(u.created_at)` as a `DATE` value for displaying and `GROUPing BY`.  (Unless you really want "days_ago".)